# Buttons not showing inside navigation bar on laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I had this html and css code that worked fine:
https://codepen.io/lirdi/pen/OJxMrOZ

Than I created a layout file where I added this code
https://codepen.io/lirdi/pen/WNZeoza
i used`@extends('layouts.layout') @extends('layouts.footer')` on my main page ,
`@section('content')` on the part i want to extend
and in the layout file ``@yield('content')```

and a `footer.blade.php` with this code:

```
<footer class="fixed_footer">
  <div class="Content">
    <p>bla</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Now I am getting this result:

[image]

With the buttons showing down the nav bar.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70252186/edit) and include all relevant code as embedded code (like you did for your `footer.blade.php`). Posting code **only** via external resources is not acceptable on Stackoverflow (those can still be included for functionality examples)

Comment: it's a long code so i decided to paste it via codepen

Comment: Then trim it to only include the relevant bits. Like I said, you can keep those codepen links for reference, but questions on Stackoverflow need to be self-contained enough on Stackoverflow that people do not need to rely on external sources to help.

Comment: is it ok now, i added the code part that makes the difference

Comment: You can't `@extend()` multiple files like that; did you mean to do `@includes('footer')` instead? Also, your Codepens don't seem to show this properly (likely due to them not being `.blade.php` files), which is why I'm asking for you to the include only the main parts of your `.blade.php` files. I'll ask again, please edit your question to show each distinct file, and the `@()` directives you're calling for your layout.